# Running Ginkgo test suite (BeforeSuite setup before any spec is ran

Tags: unit-testing, go, ginkgo

I am experiencing with Ginkgo (and Gomega) packages for unit testing Go(lang) Rest API.

I need to use global setup which should be achievable by defining

```
var _ = BeforeSuite(func() {...})
```

Then each spec (concrete `<file>_test.go`) should run after this global setup. Unfortunately I cannot make this happen...

My suite file name is `handlers_suite_test.go` and my first test spec name is `cartContentsHandler_test.go`. It seems to me Ginkgo runs the test files in alphabetical order making the `cartContentsHandler_test.go` to run **before** `handlers_suite_test.go`. I have put some `log()` call into both files and unfortunately they just confirm my findings...

This is really unhappy situation as I cannot make my tests running at all... I need to make sure that an `httptest.Server` and DB pool connection are set up and running before all specs.

**Do you know what to do in order to make the suite_test to run as the very first file before test specs?** (I already tried to name the suite file as `_suite_test.go` but in this case it looks like suite is not even executed at all).

My `handlers_suite_test.go`:

```
package handlers_test

import (
    "<PROJ>/config"
    "<PROJ>/lib"
    "<PROJ>/router"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"

    "log"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

var r *mux.Router
var s *httptest.Server
var serverURL string

func TestHandlers(t *testing.T) {
    RegisterFailHandler(Fail)
    RunSpecs(t, "Caracal Handlers Suite")
}

var _ = BeforeSuite(func() {
    r = router.NewRouter()
    s = httptest.NewServer(r)
    Expect(len(s.URL)).To(BeNumerically(">", 0))
    serverURL = s.URL
    log.Print("###" + serverURL + "###\n\n") // ==> THIS PRINTS MUCH LATER AFTER log.Print() in cartContentsHandler_test.go

    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    cfg := config.ReadCfg(cwd + "/../config/config.json").DB
    lib.DB = lib.InitDB(cfg)
    err := lib.DB.Ping()
    Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
})

var _ = AfterSuite(func() {
    //  lib.DB.Close() // ==> this was running into Panic...
    s.Close()
})
```

My `cartContensHandler_test.go`:

package handlers_test

```
import (
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"

    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

var _ = Describe("Handlers/CartContentsHandler", func() {
    Describe("Retrieves all available cart content types", func() {
        Context("No query string parameters", func() {
            var rdr *strings.Reader
            var req *http.Request
            var res *http.Response
            var err error
            var url = serverURL + "/cart-contents"

            log.Print(url)

            It("Makes a GET request", func() {
                rdr = strings.NewReader("")
                req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", url, rdr)
                Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
            })

            It("retrieves a response", func() {
                res, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
                Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
            })

            It("Returns HTTP 200 OK", func() {
                Expect(res.StatusCode).To(BeNumerically("==", http.StatusOK)) // ==> NOW THIS RETURNS 404 as request is to URL without server part
            })
        })
    })
})
```

When in <PROJ> root, I run the tests this way:

```
ginkgo handlers -cover --v
```

Comment: What happens if you put a log.Print inside the `It` functions in cartContensHandler_test.go?

Comment: Hmm, so adding new `log.Print()` inside `It` outputs really after the print in `BeforeSuite`! I'll move the spec "setup" code into `It` and will try it out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens is that `BeforeSuite` registers a function that will be executed before the test suite, and `It` registers a test function that will be part of the test suite. The callbacks to `Describe` and `Context` are executed immediately. So you must put everything that depends on `BeforeSuite` into `It`.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks!!! So finally I can run tests for one package with one global setup!!! Hooray!!! And using Ginkgo and Gomega the unit tests also look like what I was used to from PHP or JS world :-)

Answer (score 3):

To guarantee that the `BeforeSuite` will run the necessary global setup before the local setup for a `Describe` block, you should use [`BeforeEach`](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#extracting-common-setup-beforeeach):

In your suite:

```
var serverURL string

var _ = BeforeSuite(func() {
    r = router.NewRouter()
    s = httptest.NewServer(r)
    serverURL = s.URL
})
```

and in the test:

```
var _ = Describe("Handlers/CartContentsHandler", func() {
  var url url.URL

  BeforeEach(func() {
    url = serverURL + "/cart-contents"
  })

  It("Makes a GET request", func() {
    # ....
  })
})
```